# How to connect to Internet from Windows 7 laptop tethered over blue tooth to Samsung S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, bluetooth, windows, internet

Android Samsung S4: Tethering and Mobile Hotspots > Bluetooth (enabled)
Windows 7 laptop: Bluetooth enabled, paired with Samsung S4.

Windows Bluetooth Device Control window opens.
By default, the Samsung S4 has (Disconnected) below it, even though they were just paired & my laptop has no Internet connection.

My S4 has a working Internet connection.

[image]

If I try to click Connect, under Windows Bluetooth Device Control > Personal Network and Communication, a green tick appears over the Bluetooh icon located between the diagram of the laptop and the S4 at the top of the Bluetooth Device Control window. However, it reverts back to the default bluetooth icon, and the the S4 continues to display (Disconnected) below it.

I have download the [Samsung Android USB Drivers for Windows](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117), and the S4 displays as a device with no driver problems in Windows Device Manager.

**How do I have my Windows 7 laptop use my Samsung S4's mobile Internet connection while tethered over bluetooth?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps which I follow:

1.Goto `Settings` then tap on `more settings` under wireless & network.

<sub>(Click the images to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Wireless and network]

2.Tap on `Tethering & portable hotspot` under Network

[image: IMG: Tethering & portable hotspot]

3.Next tap on `Bluetooth tethering` to enable Bluetooth tethering

[image: IMG: Bluetooth tethering]

Now Pair your Device to your Computer, to do this...

1.Hit the `Bluetooth Icon in the system tray`

[image: IMG: Bluetooth Icon in the system tray]

2.Click “Add a Device”

[image: Bluetooth- Add a device]

3.Wait for it to search for your Bluetooth Internet Access Point, then click to select it and press “Next”

[image: Bluetooth- Sridhar device]

4.Click “Yes” then click “Next”

[image: Bluetooth- Sridhar device Pairing]

5.Wait till your Computer to install the drivers.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: Bluetooth- Sridhar device has been Setup]

6.Now the Bluetooth access point has been setup.

7.Click the system tray, then right click on the Bluetooth icon and then hit **`Join a Personal Area Network`**

[image: IMG: Bluetooth Icon in the system tray]
[image: IMG: Bluetooth Icon in the system tray]

Else,

7. Goto Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers
8. Right Click your device and connect using Access Point

[image: IMG: Sridhar Device]

> Note : Again your device have not connected means try these

***Setting up the modem***

On the PC, Click Control Panel

Right-click on the Bluetooth icon in System tray, click Add

An Add Bluetooth Device Wizard will appear

Select My device is set up and ready to be found

Click Next

Select the handset from the list and click Next

Select Let me choose my own passkey

Type 4 to 16 digit passkey (example: 1234) in the available field

Click Pair Now

On the handset, enter the same Passcode (Passkey) entered on the PC Press OK

An Accept connection request prompt will appear, press Yes

Ensure that Dial-up networking (DUN) is checked

Click Next

On the PC, click Finish

Then Click Control Panel

Double-click Phone and Modem Options

Click Modems tab

Select Bluetooth Modem

Click Properties button

On the General tab, click Change settings button

If a User Account Control prompt appears, click Continue

Click Advanced tab

In the Extra initialization commands field, type `at+cgdcont=1,"IP","internet"`

Click OK and OK again.

***Setting up the connection***

On the PC, return to the Control Panel

Double-click Network and Sharing Center icon

Click Set up a connection or network

Select Setup a dial up Connection

Click Next

If prompted, Select No, Create a new connection

Click Next

Click Dial-up

If prompted, click Bluetooth Modem

In the Dial-up phone number, field, type `*99***1#` or `*99#`

Leave the User name and Password fields blank

In the Connection Name field, type the corresponding `APN` *(Ex: XXXX.com or YYYY.internet)*

To Know APN :

On the Mobile, Goto Settings\More settings\Mobile Networks\Access Point Names and then Tap the required network to view it

<sub>(Click the image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Mobile Networks]

Select from the available options

***Setting up the connection***

On the PC, click Connect

On the handset, an Accept connection request prompt will appear, press Yes

If a Set Network Location prompt appears, click Cancel

Comment: Sridhar, that's great, very comprehensive answer. The trick for me, was turning Bluetooth tethering on, before pairing the devices (I believe). Thank you! :-)

Comment: @Steve: Try BlueSoleil  (Third Party) also, which worked for me when windows 7 Bluetooth fails

Comment: Cheers Sridhar.